# DROP Materialized View

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views

I've a problem by dropping a Materialized View in Oracle.

I've got the Error Message : "Disconnected Process"
And now the ERROR 3113.

Does anyone can give me a hint?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through below link for better understanding of your issue..
[network disconnected](http://dba-oracle.com/m_ora_03113_end_of_file_on_communications_channel.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with the connection. Finaly we restarted the database.
That is not the best way. But it works.